# What is basic unit of ui of jetpack compose?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

Android xml basic unit of ui is View.
Flutter basic unit of ui is Widget.

Then, What is basic unit of Jetpack Compose?

I'm thinking about what to end compose ui function name with.
Like. SearchView, SearchWidget, SearchCompose, SearchUI, SearchComponent etc...

What do you all think?

Comment: Very good question. Anyone who has done swiftui knows that all are views, no matter the size, they are processed according to the view, which is simple and unified and easy to understand.

Comment: @gaohomway As you advised, I'll use "view". Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you're trying to accomplish. If you need a basic view to display background for instance, `Surface` will do the job. If you'd like an empty view to space your items – although padding would do the same – then you could use `Spacer`

Comment: What he needs is a unified rule, because there are no rules, so that developers can not believe that they are right or wrong